# Automatic save of render image after finishing

Tags: rendering

Is it possible to have blender save the single image when it finishes rendering it? I dont want to wait until its done as I let it render during the night. Ideally, I would want the PC to turn off as well when finished rendering. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could write a short python script, that renders your image from command line (includes output folder) and once that's done it shuts down the pc. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34039845/how-to-shutdown-a-computer-using-python, https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/render.html

Comment: Hello :). There's a very simple addon from Gleb Alexandrov, that allows you to do exactly that https://www.creativeshrimp.com/renderburst.html

Comment: You can try [loom](https://github.com/p2or/blender-loom), allows automatic rendering via command line and the [batch dialog](https://github.com/p2or/blender-loom#user-content-loom-batch-dialog-ctrlshiftaltf12) has an option to shutdown when the rendering is finished.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a "file output" with the correct path in the composition workspace. The plugged image will automatically be copied to that place once rendering is done. You can add multiple file outputs so that the image is copied to multiple paths once rendered, or at differents steps of the compositing.

[image]

You can write a python script for the shutdown as explained by @WhatAMesh or alternatively if you are on windows OS, go into command line (<kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and type "cmd" ) and type "shutdown /s /t *" without the parentheses where * is the number of seconds you expect the rendering will take. I suggest inputting a greater value than what's expected.

Answer (score 4):

Daily build includes addon **Auto Save Render** under **Testing** tab

[image: addon]

I wanted to paste .py file (add-on) here for user of official build, but I don't know how to :)